# AttributeError: 'Stud' object has no attribute 'sno' at line no.11

Tags: python, class, object, constructor

program is:

```
class Stud:
    def __init__(self):
        self.displval()
        print("I am Constructor")    
        self.sno = int(input("Enter the roll number"))
        self.sname = (input("Enter the Name"))
    def displval(self):
        print("="*50)
        print(self.sno)
        print(self.sname)

so = Stud()
```

Comment: You are calling `displval` *before* you set the two attributes it tries to display.

Comment: `Stud.__init__` should take values as arguments, rather than prompting the user for values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Stud:
    def __init__(self):

        print("I am Constructor")
        self.sno = int(input("Enter the roll number"))
        self.sname = (input("Enter the Name"))
        self.displval()

    def displval(self):
        print("="*50)
        print(self.sno)
        print(self.sname)

so = Stud()
```

Put the `self.displval()` at the end.  You're calling it before it has any `self.[value]` to pass into the method.

Comment: No worries, you shouldn't really print in the __init__ method though.  I'd look at creating a new `def input(self)` method and have them seperate.  So the __init__ is only setting up the self.parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are calling `self.displval` *before* you set the attributes it tries to display.

```
class Stud:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am Constructor")    
        self.sno = int(input("Enter the roll number"))
        self.sname = (input("Enter the Name"))
        self.displval()

    def displval(self):
        print("="*50)
        print(self.sno)
        print(self.sname)
```

However, `__init__` is doing too much work. It should receive values as arguments and simply set the attributes. If you want `Stud` to provide a way to collect those arguments from the user, define an additional class method. (It's also debatable whether `__init__` should be printing anything to standard output, but I'll leave that for now.)

```
class Stud:
    def __init__(self, sno, sname):
        self.sno = sno
        self.sname = sname
        self.displval()

    @classmethod
    def create_with_user_input(cls):
        sno = int(input("Enter the roll number"))
        sname = (input("Enter the Name"))
        return cls(sno, sname)

    def displval(self):
        print("="*50)
        print(self.sno)
        print(self.sname)

so = Stud.create_from_user_input()
```